# 'override' can only be specified on class members

Tags: xcode6

I'm getting an error message in relation to an 'override func'.  It seems to be saying that 'viewWillAppear' is not a class member.

Can anyone tell me how I would fix this?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import CoreData

class SoundListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,     UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!    
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()    
var sounds: [Sound] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) { // 'override' can only be specified on class members
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: try it outside of viewDidLoad

Comment: Is this swift ? You should specify so in the tag.

Comment: I tried placing it outside of viewDidLoad and got even more error messages.